# Logo looks different after uploading

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface, graphical-logo

[image]

Hi, in the first picture you can see what logo I want to upload.
But, after uploading it changes it's color specification a little bit, shown in the second picture (right down corner). It adds the black color.
Could you please help me out?

The code I'm using:

```
axes(handles.axes13)
imshow('logo4.png')
```

[image]

Comment: I assume it is related to the 4rth color channel, transparency. Replace transparent pixels with white ones.

Comment: How can I do that?
You mean doing that in Matlab or changing the picture?

Comment: I have tried this:

    set(gca, ’Color’, ’none’)

But doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the original png. Here, the top of the logo is set as transparent while the bottom is white. So, when you plot the images using imshow, you have this effect. Either you change the logo png or you can pretend as this problem never existed by setting the background color as white when you load the image.

```
logo4 = imread('logo4.png,'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1]);
imshow(logo4)
```

The problem is still there, it´s just someone else´s problem now.

profit.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes you need to solve someone else´s problems, sometimes you just need to pass them on to the next guy in the line.